# How can I rig eyelids and eyelashes together to achieve synchronized movement?

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm making a character for a Unity game project, but I'm facing issues with rigging. How can I rig the eyelids and eyelashes together to achieve synchronized movement?

Head and eyelashes are separate objects. Should I merge them into one object? Do I need to delete any bones?

[image]

Comment: Hello, yes you can join eyelash and eyelid to the head, as for the rigging, make sur that they are correctly weight painted, or maybe, for more precision, do it manually with the Assign button under the vertex groups list